# How to find the side lengths of a triangle given the hypotenuse length and tangent?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Let's say there is a triangle with hypotenuse length 225 and tangent ratio 15/8, is there a method short of trial and error to find the length of the opposite and adjacent sides?

Comment: You have two equations say $tan θ = b/a$ and $a^2 + b^2 = h^2$ from which you can easily derive and solve a quadratic equation in $a$ and hence know $b$.

Comment: Easily is subjective.  I have no idea how to do what you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sides are $15x$ and $8x$.

Using the Pythagorean Theorem you have $ (15x)^2 + ( 8x)^2 =225^2.$

That results in $x^2 = \frac {225^2}{289} $ or $x=13.235$

Thus the sides are  approximately $105.88$ and $198.52$

Comment: I had used the wrong ratio in the initial question as I mentioned in the other answer. The correct tangent is 15/8. I'll give it a try nonetheless, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your correction. The method is the same. You just get a more balanced result.

Comment: I have changed my numbers to reflect your new data.

Comment: This worked and makes complete sense.  You use x as a means of finding the total multiplier, then times that by the respective 15 or 8 to get the exact length.  Accepted for simplicity. Thanks!

Comment: Correct. Thanks for your good judgment.

Answer (score 1):

We can draw 2 triangles with big side parallel to hypotenuse $225$ sides $8,17$

$$=\sqrt {15^2+8^2} = 17 $$

Magnification ratio $$ m=\dfrac{225}{17}$$

So the sides are

$$ 8m, 15m \, .$$

Comment: Nice addition to the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

$a^2 + b^2 = 225\\
\frac {b}{a} = \frac {18}{5}\\
b = \frac {18}{5}a\\
b^2 = \frac {18^2}{5^2}a^2\\
a^2+b^2 = \frac {18^2+5^2}{5^2} a^2 = 225\\
225 = 15^2\\
a^2 = \frac {15^2\cdot 5^2}{18^2+5^2}\\
a = \frac {5\cdot 15}{\sqrt {18^2+5^2}}\\
b = \frac {18\cdot 15}{\sqrt {18^2+5^2}}$

Comment: Wow, I'm sorry... I had put the wrong tangent in the question. It's actually 15/8.  This process looks good though, I'll give it a try with the correct ratio.  Thank you :)

Comment: I'm following the steps, but I'm a bit confused as to how you arrived at step 4, why are you adding 5^2 in the numerator?

Comment: $a^2+b^2 = a^2 + \frac {18^2}{5^2}a^2 = \frac {5^2}{5^2} a^2 + \frac {18^2}{5^2}a^2 = \frac {18^2+5^2}{5^2}a^2$

Comment: You will get a rational number in the answer if you use that ratio.